# Reading TCURR table with RFC_READ_TABLE truncates the rate value

Tags: c#, abap, sap-dotnet-connector

I'm trying to read data from SAP ECC using Microsoft .NET. For this, I am using the [SAP Connector for Microsoft .NET 3.0](https://support.sap.com/en/product/connectors/msnet.html) Following is the code to retrieve the data, I'm getting the results too. However, I found that the exchange rate value is having a * if it exceeds 7 characters.

```
        ECCDestinationConfig cfg = new ECCDestinationConfig();

        RfcDestinationManager.RegisterDestinationConfiguration(cfg);

        RfcDestination dest = RfcDestinationManager.GetDestination("mySAPdestination");

        RfcRepository repo = dest.Repository;


        IRfcFunction testfn = repo.CreateFunction("RFC_READ_TABLE");
        testfn.SetValue("QUERY_TABLE", "TCURR");

        // fields will be separated by semicolon
        testfn.SetValue("DELIMITER", ";");

        // Parameter table FIELDS contains the columns you want to receive
        // here we query 3 fields, FCURR, TCURR and UKURS
        IRfcTable fieldsTable = testfn.GetTable("FIELDS");
        fieldsTable.Append();
        fieldsTable.SetValue("FIELDNAME", "FCURR");
        fieldsTable.Append();
        fieldsTable.SetValue("FIELDNAME", "TCURR");
        fieldsTable.Append();
        fieldsTable.SetValue("FIELDNAME", "UKURS");
        fieldsTable.Append();
        fieldsTable.SetValue("FIELDNAME", "GDATU");

        // the table OPTIONS contains the WHERE condition(s) of your query           
        // several conditions have to be concatenated in ABAP syntax, for instance with AND or OR
        IRfcTable optsTable = testfn.GetTable("OPTIONS");

        var dateVal = 99999999 - 20190701;
        optsTable.Append();
        optsTable.SetValue("TEXT", "gdatu = '" + dateVal + "' and KURST = 'EURX'");

        testfn.Invoke(dest);
```

Values are as follows:

[image]

How to get the full value without any truncation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just ran into the worst limitation of `RFC_READ_TABLE`.

Its error is to return field values based on internal length and truncating the rest, rather than using the output length. `TCURR-UKURS` is a BCD decimal packed field of length `9,5` (9 bytes = 17 digits, including 5 digits after the decimal point) and an output length of 12. Unfortunately, `RFC_READ_TABLE` outputs the result on 9 characters, so a value of `105.48000-` takes 10 characters is too long, so ABAP default logic is to set the `*` overflow character on the leftmost character (`*5.48000-`).

Either you create another RFC-enabled function module at SAP/ABAP side, or you access directly the SAP database (classic RDBMS connected to SAP server).

Comment: any other functions to read these exchange rates? i dont have the access to the SAP/ABAP function, i'm programming from .NET to use them using the connector as mentioned in the question. Franckly speaking i'm new to these. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Just an addition to Sandra perfect explanation about this issue. Yes, the only solution here would be writing a custom module for fetching remote records.

If you don't want to rewrite it from scratch the simplest solution would be to copy `RFC_READ_TABLE` into Z module and change line 137

```
FIELDS_INT-LENGTH_DST = TABLE_STRUCTURE-LENG.
```

to

```
FIELDS_INT-LENGTH_DST = TABLE_STRUCTURE-OUTPUTLEN.
```

This solves the problem.

**UPDATE**: try `BAPI_EXCHANGERATE_GETDETAIL` BAPI, it is RFC-enabled and reads rates correctly. The interface is quite self-explanatory, the only difference is that date should be in native format, not in inverted:

```
CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_EXCHANGERATE_GETDETAIL'
  EXPORTING
    rate_type  = 'EURO'
    from_curr  = 'USD'
    to_currncy = 'EUR'
    date       = '20190101'
  IMPORTING
    exch_rate  = rates
    return     = return.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however i dont have access to the SAP functions. Im using .NET to consume them. Do you have other way of accessing the exchange rates for a specified dates?

Comment: Exposing exchange rates [via web-services](http://saptechnical.com/Tutorials/Others/ABAPWebservices/create.htm) is a very common way but it also requires access to SAP system

Comment: This BAPI needs to be called for every single currency? is there any way to get the full list for a date?

Comment: For single. The date is mandatory parameter which accepts only single values, so you cannot fetch a batch of currency rates for different dates, only one by one.

Comment: `is there any way to get the full list for a date?` I suppose no. Without additional configurations on SAP side the answer is no.

Answer (score 1):

Use BBP_RFC_READ_TABLE. It is still not the best but it does one thing right which RFC_READ_TABLE did not: one additional byte for the decimal sign.

No need to go through all the ordeal if you only look for patching the decimal issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is the sample code used with SAP connector for .NET, let it be helpful for someone who looks for the same. Thanks for all those who helped.

```
        var RateForDate = 20190701;

        ECCDestinationConfig cfg = new ECCDestinationConfig();
        RfcDestinationManager.RegisterDestinationConfiguration(cfg);
        RfcDestination dest = RfcDestinationManager.GetDestination("mySAPdestination");
        RfcRepository repo = dest.Repository;


        IRfcFunction sapFunction = repo.CreateFunction("RFC_READ_TABLE");
        sapFunction.SetValue("QUERY_TABLE", "TCURR");
        // fields will be separated by semicolon
        sapFunction.SetValue("DELIMITER", ";");

        // Parameter table FIELDS contains the columns you want to receive
        // here we query 3 fields, FCURR, TCURR and UKURS
        IRfcTable fieldsTable = sapFunction.GetTable("FIELDS");
        fieldsTable.Append();
        fieldsTable.SetValue("FIELDNAME", "FCURR");
        //fieldsTable.Append();
        //fieldsTable.SetValue("FIELDNAME", "TCURR");
        //fieldsTable.Append();
        //fieldsTable.SetValue("FIELDNAME", "UKURS");


        // the table OPTIONS contains the WHERE condition(s) of your query
        // here a single condition, KUNNR is to be 0012345600
        // several conditions have to be concatenated in ABAP syntax, for instance with AND or OR
        IRfcTable optsTable = sapFunction.GetTable("OPTIONS");

        var dateVal = 99999999 - RateForDate;
        optsTable.Append();
        optsTable.SetValue("TEXT", "gdatu = '" + dateVal + "' and KURST = 'EURX'");

        sapFunction.Invoke(dest);

        var companyCodeList = sapFunction.GetTable("DATA");
        DataTable Currencies = companyCodeList.ToDataTable("DATA");

        //Add additional column for rates
        Currencies.Columns.Add("Rate", typeof(double));

        //------------------
        sapFunction = repo.CreateFunction("BAPI_EXCHANGERATE_GETDETAIL");
        //rate type of your system
        sapFunction.SetValue("rate_type", "EURX");
        sapFunction.SetValue("date", RateForDate.ToString());
        //Main currency of your system
        sapFunction.SetValue("to_currncy", "EUR");

        foreach (DataRow item in Currencies.Rows)
        {
            sapFunction.SetValue("from_curr", item[0].ToString());
            sapFunction.Invoke(dest);
            IRfcStructure impStruct = sapFunction.GetStructure("EXCH_RATE");
            item["Rate"] = impStruct.GetDouble("EXCH_RATE_V");
        }


        dtCompanies.DataContext = Currencies;     
        RfcDestinationManager.UnregisterDestinationConfiguration(cfg);
```